# How to add a URL as a Shape to a Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word, shapes

I am trying to place a QR code generated through an API (api.qrserver,com) into a Word table using VBA. For certain reasons, using "DisplayBarcode" is not possible.

This is the call to the API:

```
sURL = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=" & UTF8_URL_Encode(VBA.Replace(QR_Value, " ", "+")) & "&size=240x240"
```

It seems to work. I tried a GET command and retrieved a string that, as I interpret, contains the QR code in PNG format.

When I try to add the picture as a Shape using

```
Set objGrafik = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(sURL, True)
```

the call fails with

> runtime error 5152

As far as I could determine the AddPicture method expects a pure filename and does not allow any of the following characters: /|?*<>:".

I also tried to store the GET result in an object variable:

```
Set oQRCode = http.responseText
```

but there I get the error

> object required

How do I either make the URL assignment work or store the result as a picture?

Comment: I'm guessing it expects the file name in `content-disposition`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that any of the ways you could insert something into Word (e.g. `Shapes.AddPicture`, `InlineShapes.AddPicture`, `Range.InsertFile` etc. will let you do that from any old https Url, although it seems to work for some Urls.

However, as it happens, you can use an INCLUDEPICTURE field to do it. FOr example

```
{ INCLUDEPICTURE https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=Test&size=100x100 }
```

Here's some sample VBA to do that

```
Sub insertqrcode()
Dim sUrl As String
Dim f As Word.Field
Dim r1 As Word.Range
Dim r2 As Word.Range

' This is just a test - plug your own Url in.
sUrl = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=abcdef&size=100x100"
' Pick an empty test cell in a table
Set r1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(5, 4).Range
' We have to remove the end of cell character to add the field to the range
' Simplify
Set r2 = r1.Duplicate
r2.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart
Set f = r2.Fields.Add(r2, WdFieldType.wdFieldIncludePicture, sUrl, False)
' If you don't want the field code any more, do this
f.Unlink
' check that we have a new inline shape that we could work with more
' if necessary
Debug.Print r1.InlineShapes.count
Set f = Nothing
Set r2 = Nothing
Set r1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Using INCLUDEPICTURE works even on the current version of Mac Word (although I haven't tested that specific piece of VBA on Mac).

The only other way I have seen to do it uses WinHTTP to get the result from the web service, ADODB to stream it out to a local disk file, then AddPicture or whatever to include that file, so much more complicated and won't work on Mac either.