# Add an image to Word using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ms-word

As stated in the Title, I would like to add an image into a Word document. Though my goal is to NOT use a path (stating where the image is located).

**Like this: **

> $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
> $word.visible = $true
> $document = $word.documents.Add()
> $selection = $word.selection
> $newInlineShape = $selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture($path)

But rather using some type of Base64String, so that this skript works with every device, regardless if the image path doesn't exist.

**My attempt**:

> $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
> $word.visible = $true
>
> $document = $word.documents.Add()
> $selection = $word.selection
>
> $base64ImageString = [Convert]::ToBase64String((Get-Content $path -encoding byte))
> $imageBytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($base64ImageString)
> $ms = New-Object IO.MemoryStream($imageBytes, 0, $imageBytes.Length)
> $ms.Write($imageBytes, 0, $imageBytes.Length);
> $alkanelogo = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromStream($ms, $true)
>
> $pictureBox = new-object Windows.Forms.PictureBox
> $pictureBox.Width =  $alkanelogo.Size.Width;
> $pictureBox.Height =  $alkanelogo.Size.Height;
> $pictureBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(153,223)
> $pictureBox.Image = $alkanelogo;
>
> $newInlineShape = $selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture($pictureBox.Image)

Note: The variable "$path" is only here as a placeholder

Comment: The signature for ```InlineShapes.AddPicture``` is ```expression. AddPicture( _FileName_ , _LinkToFile_ , _SaveWithDocument_ , _Range_ )``` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshapes.addpicture). There’s no option to pass a picture object so you’ll need to give a file path I think. However, since you’re proposing to load a base64 string from a file, why not just ship the image file with your script instead of the base64 string file and give the path to that in your call to ```AddPicture```?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean with "ship the image file with your script..."?

Comment: I mean deploy / distribute the image file when you deploy / distribute your script - if you're already able to deploy a text file with the image base64 encoded you can just deploy the image file instead and use the path to it from the location the script is running from (```$PSScriptRoot\myimage.png``` or whatever)...

Comment: Wouldn't I have to add the path to every User then? And the image I'm working with is from the internet...

Comment: Your sample code loads a base64 string from a text file. If you're reading from a url that's an important difference - you should update your sample code to reflect that so you can get a better answer. You should also explain how this needs to work with mutliple users... In short though, the Word API only appears to support adding pictures from a file so you may just have to create a temp file in a known location and delete it again after inserting into the document. (If you don't have write permissions to the disk you could maybe paste via the clipboard but that's a lot more fragiule).

Comment: I suggest that if you want to get images from URLs as well as the local/network file system, you model your code on the approach I have described in my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74937898/how-to-avoid-runtime-error-5152-when-trying-to-add-a-url-as-shape-to-a-word-docu/74943664#74943664 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I downloaded the image to my local computer, converted it to a base64 string and then back to an image.
So that this script works with every user regardless of there path, I built in it to download the file to a specific path (that I created).
Powershell will then extract the image from the path I created.

```
$filepath = 'C:\temp\image.png'
$folderpath = 'C:\temp\'

if([System.IO.File]::Exists($filepath -or $folderpath)){
    rmdir 'C:\temp\image.png'

    $b64 = "AAA..."


    $bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($b64)
    [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filepath, $bytes)
}else{ 
    mkdir 'C:\temp\' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $b64 = "AAA..."


    $bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($b64)
    [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($filepath, $bytes)
}
```